# Tf tree getting messed up when launching freenect.launch

Tags: navigation, odometry, kinect, ros-kinetic, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just launching the robot description .
[image: image description]

After launching freenect

```
roslaunch freenect_launch freenect.launch
```

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283932/tf-tree-getting-messed-up-when-launching-freenect.launch/) by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on ROS Answers with karma: 142 on 2018-02-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2018-03-01**:
The launch file has a "publish_tf" argument, try with this argument set to false

**Comment by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on 2018-03-01**:
Did the job , thank you! (@humpelstilzchen)

**Comment by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on 2018-03-01**:
[camera/camera_nodelet_manager-1] process has died [pid 12709, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=camera_nodelet_manager __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/eeb501ca-1d10-11e8-875b-00044b65e5df/camera-camera_nodelet_manager-1.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/eeb501c

**Comment by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on 2018-03-01**:
Now i am getting the above error , kinect launches and then crashes
.

**Comment by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on 2018-03-01**:
I have tried hooking it upto RPI3 , same error .

I am now using a Nvidia Jetson TX1 , still the same error persists .

Any ideas on how to get around this problem ?

**Comment by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on 2018-03-01**:
When i am trying to run gmapping , i get the following error .

Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: Could not find a connection between 'map' and 'base_link' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnec

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2018-03-01**:
Thats a new question, also look at the mentioned log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your `TF`  tree is not fully connected. You need to publish the transformation between your `base_link` and `camera _link`

---

Originally posted by [Gayan Brahmanage](https://answers.ros.org/users/26769/gayan-brahmanage/) with karma: 929 on 2018-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on 2018-03-06**:
Had to set the tf on freenect.launch to not publish tf , that was conflicting with my robot tf.